# Integral $\int\frac{1}{z}dz$ of an open area

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have to calculate the integral of an open area.

I calculated the integral of a closed area and next substracted the “extra” line.

The answer I become is $2\pi i - ln(\sqrt{2})$ in stead of $2\pi i + ln(\sqrt{2})$

What did i do wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the third line, you may want to have $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dz}{z} = \left[\log z\right]_{1}^{2}$. Also, the correct answer is $2\pi i + \log 2$.

Comment: @SangchulLee What a basic fault! Thnx!!!

Comment: @SangchulLee How do you see the order of the pole z = 0 in this case?

Comment: I think I am not following your question... It is clear that $\frac{1}{z}$ has a simple pole at $z = 0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I Am confused with an other example i think. I saw the function $\frac{1}{z^2sin(z)}$ and in this case the pole in z = 0 was of order 3. I just don't know how to see the order of a pole...

Comment: Recall that: if $f$ is holomorphic on a domain $D$, then a point $a\in D$ is called a pole if $|f(z)|\to\infty$ as $z\to a$. It can be proved that there exists an integer $n\geq1$ such that $z^n f(z)$ converges to a non-zero constant as $z\to a$, and this $n$ is called the order of $a$. In your example, $$z^3\cdot\frac{1}{z^2\sin z}=\frac{z}{\sin z}\xrightarrow[z\to0]{}1$$ and hence the order of pole is $3$. Alternatively, $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $a$ if it admits the Laurent expansion $$f(z)=\sum_{k=-n}^{\infty}a_k(z-a)^k$$ with $a_{-n}\neq0$ near $z=a$.